I can't access my Blend file. There's an error that reads "failed to read blend file - missing DNA block"
Blender randomly quit while I was working. I tried to re-open my file and I can't. There's an error message displayed indicating "missing DNA block" and it can't read the file. I'm new to Blender. Is this fixable? Is there a way to prevent it?

See if File > Recover > Autosave allows you to load a recent version. - This will depend how you have Edit > Preferences > Save & Load > Auto-Save set up of course... Mine's set to 1 minute so I wouldn't lose much if I ever has a crash.

That worked. Thanks!

@JohnEason Is there a way to save a backup of the backup? Like how you can keep 2 older version when saving manually? I've had a couple instances where even the autosave file was corrupted. It's rare but it happens

Not automatically to my knowledge, but if the backup was corrupted, surely a backup of that would be corrupted too?

@Philadelphia_Collins83 I've never heard of an error like that so I'm not sure how you could prevent it if you don't know what's caused it in the first place!
